Acumatica how to modify opportunity stageid Even if quote is accepted
The standard behavior is to disable modifications of some opportunity Fields when quote is not on hold.
I don’t find in source code where is this rule and don’t know how to change this behavior.

Could you add more details? Which screen are you working with - Sales Quote, Project Quote, or Opportunity? And which fields are you trying to edit?

Opportunity is created on screen CR304000, quote on screen CR304500. I would like to edit stageID in CR304000 but there is a « yellow message » ‘One or more settings in the opportunity cannot be modified because the primary quote status is other than draft ´ on the field’opportunity id’

Is this for single opportunity, or you want to write a code that does it? As of the source code, which does it, check also workflows scenarios for CR304000

The problem is for each single opportunity. I would like to disable the source code which doesnt allow to modify Opportunity stageID when Sales Quote is not on hold. I suppose it is in OpportunityMaint graph but maybe it's in one of its extensions. The problem is when Opportunity is in Open Status with 2 different behaviors according the status of the Sales Quote. There is no Auto-Run action in this Workflow.

Try this workflow extension, you may need to compile it into a DLL.
using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.WorkflowAPI;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CR.Workflows;

namespace Customization;

public class OpportunityWorkflowExt : 
    PXGraphExtension<OpportunityWorkflow, OpportunityMaint>
{
    public override void Configure(PXScreenConfiguration config)
    {
        var context = config.GetScreenConfigurationContext<OpportunityMaint, CROpportunity>();

        context.UpdateScreenConfigurationFor(screen =>
            screen
                .UpdateDefaultFlow(flows =>
                    flows.WithFlowStates(flowStates =>
                    {
                        flowStates.Update<OpportunityStatus.won>(state =>
                            state.WithFieldStates(fs =>
                                fs.AddField<CROpportunity.stageID>()));
                        flowStates.Update<OpportunityStatus.lost>(state =>
                            state.WithFieldStates(fs =>
                                fs.AddField<CROpportunity.stageID>()));
                    })));
    }
}

